# lim [f(x) + g(x)] = lim f(x) + lim g(x) but why can't we solve this question in that way.

Tags: calculus

In this question $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to∞}(\frac{1+2+3+. . .+n}{n^2})$$
We can calculate the limit by writing 1+2+3+...+n as $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$
And the final answer will be $\frac{1}{2}$.
But if we want to split up the terms into individual limits as $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to∞}(\frac{1}{n^2})+ \displaystyle \lim_{n\to∞}(\frac{2}{n^2}) + \displaystyle \lim_{n\to∞}(\frac{3}{n^2})+...+\displaystyle \lim_{n\to∞}(\frac{n}{n^2})$$ and if we apply limit in this it will turn out to be 0. So why is it not possible to apply this identity or rule in this question or am I missing out on something.

Comment: You are forgetting that the number of terms is not fixed but depends on $n$. For $n=1$, you would only have one limit, for $n=2$ you would need to split this into two limits, etc...

Comment: Think of it as a large number (not infinite) of very small terms, *none of them exactly equal to zero*, being added. The contrasting factors fight, and then compromise to land on some number depending on the properties of the sum.

Comment: @Andreas I got it, thanks a lot.

Comment: @insipidintegrator yeah we can think that way too, thankyou.